# Parse error at '=': usage might be invalid Matlab syntax

Tags: matlab, parsing

Why can't I do this loop this way ?

```
for i=1:N
(Teta(2,i)-Teta(1,i))/dY=0;
end
```

I am getting this error : `Parse error at '=': usage might be invalid Matlab syntax`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot make calculations in the left side of the equals sign. Calculations can only be made in the right-hand side.

For example, like this:

```
for i=1:N
    Teta(2,i) = 0 * dY + Teta(1,i);
end
```

Without knowing anything about the application of you problem, I just moved everything but the `Teta(2,i)` from the left to the right. This will not give that error. But probably isn't the result you wish wither...